# While sorting lower case and upper case letters are treated seperately

Tags: javascript, sorting

While sorting String field

- If field is empty then it should go at the top in desc and at the bottom in asc (This is working fine)
- For Integer behaviour is fine (It considers null/undefined values and do sorting)

**Only problem is with 'Case sensitivity'**

> - It should treat 'rosy' And 'Rosy' as same and display them on after another

```js
function dynamicsort(property,order) {
    var sort_order = 1;
    if(order === "desc"){
        sort_order = -1;
    }
    return function (a, b){
        //check if one of the property is undefined
        if(a[property] == null){
                return 1 * sort_order;
        }
        if(b[property] == null){
                return -1 * sort_order;
        }
        // a should come before b in the sorted order
        if(a[property] < b[property]){
                return -1 * sort_order;
        // a should come after b in the sorted order
        }else if(a[property] > b[property]){
                return 1 * sort_order;
        // a and b are the same
        }else{
                return 0 * sort_order;
        }
    }
}
let employees = [
    {
        firstName: 'John11',
        age: 27,
        joinedDate: 'December 15, 2017'
    },
    {
        firstName: 'john22',
        lastName: 'rosy',

        age: 44,
        joinedDate: 'December 15, 2017'
    },
{
        firstName: 'SSS',
        lastName: 'SSSS',
        age: 111,
        joinedDate: 'January 15, 2019'
    },
    {
        firstName: 'Ana',
        lastName: 'Rosy',
        age: 25,
        joinedDate: 'January 15, 2019'
    },

    {
        firstName: 'Zion',
        lastName: 'Albert',
        age: 30,
        joinedDate: 'February 15, 2011'
    },
    {
        firstName: 'ben',
        lastName: 'Doe',
        joinedDate: 'December 15, 2017'
    },
];

console.log("Object to be sorted");
console.log(employees);

console.log("Sorting based on the lastName property")
console.log(employees.sort(dynamicsort("lastName","desc")));
console.log("Sorting based on the lastName property")
console.log(employees.sort(dynamicsort("lastName","asc")));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `localeCompare()` ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)) to compare the properties if they are strings.

Here is a simple example based on your code. There are other possible improvements but I don't want to change your original code too much, so I'm just showing one way you could use `localeCompare()`.

```js
function dynamicsort(property,order) {
    var sort_order = 1;
    if(order === "desc"){
        sort_order = -1;
    }
    return function (a, b){
        //check if one of the property is undefined
        if(a[property] == null){
                return 1 * sort_order;
        }
        if(b[property] == null){
                return -1 * sort_order;
        }
        // if both properties are strings use localeCompare
        if (typeof a[property] === "string" && typeof b[property] === "string") {
            return a[property].localeCompare(b[property]) * sort_order;
        }
        // a should come before b in the sorted order
        if(a[property] < b[property]){
                return -1 * sort_order;
        // a should come after b in the sorted order
        }else if(a[property] > b[property]){
                return 1 * sort_order;
        // a and b are the same
        }else{
                return 0 * sort_order;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

transform both strings [to lower case](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tolowercase.asp) [or uppercase](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_touppercase.asp) before the sort.